# How to use two arrays to create an object literal array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, object-literal

I want to create an object literal array like this

```
var data = [
      {name: 'John A. Smith', state: 'CA'},
      {name: 'Joan B. Jones', state: 'NY'}
    ];
```

`name` and `state` are stored in an array `columns`.

`John A. Smith` and `CA` are stored in array `data`.

I'm trying to write this way, but it seemed like I couldn't use the `columns[i]` before the `:`,

```
var temp = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    temp.push({
        columns[i]: data[i]
    });
}
```

Thanks Lochemage, it works for my columns. Here is my entire code:

```
var temp = [];
var tempObj = {};
for (var i=0; i<colHeads.length; i++) { // columns
    var dataArr = '$colData.get(i)'.split(",");
    for (var j = 0; j < dataArr.length; ++j) { // data
        tempObj[colHeads[i]] = dataArr[j];
    }
    temp.push(tempObj);
}
```

This `'$colData.get(i)'` seems to work with direct index (0, 1, ..), but it won't work with `i`.

By the way, `$colData` is a string array from velocity markup; it contains strings. In this particular problem, it contains

```
[0]: CA, NY
[1]: John A. Smith, Joan B. Jones
```

And I need the final result is to be the `data` array stated at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the bracket operator with your columns value instead:

```
var temp = [];
var tempObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  tempObj[columns[i]] = data[i];
}
temp.push(tempObj);
```

Comment: will this value `tempObj[columns[i]]` be replaced for each iteration?

Comment: Using the bracket operator on an object is the same as doing something like `tempObj.name = data[i]`, except it allows you to specify the property variable from a string value like 'name'. In the end, using `tempObj['name'] = 'foo'` is exactly the same as using `tempObj.name = 'foo'`

Comment: thanks, but I think my question here is insufficient, I've posted another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919292/add-different-value-to-the-same-object-literal-javascript)